# Server monitor software for Ruby on Rails

Tags: monitoring, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I'm a developer for a startup and currently looking for a server monitoring software that'll work with Ruby on Rails.

I don't have any preferences honestly. But we have an app (iOS) that'll we probably also want monitor. So it would be neat to have one software both for backend and the app.

I, barely, know of New Relic and Scout.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things you could try. There is a New Relic app for monitoring rails. You could try skyligh.io also (I have found a lot of people moving from new relic to skylight).  There's also a way to tail your log files with capistrano (http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2013/12/tailing-log-files-with-capistrano-3/) or if you feel in the need of hard work, you can try riemman (http://riemann.io/).

Good luck!